# The Apostrophe (') converts to �

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am using datatype "text" in my database to store few lines of contents. But, when displayed in my website, any words that use the the apostrophe (') for example Malaysia's converts to Malaysia �? How can i solve this?

Comment: you have to escape the strings. What scripting language are you using?

Comment: you can do the escape string in middle ware, are you using php?

Comment: What's your encoding in your database? latin? utf8? How do you put the data in the database? Is your connection utf8? Are your scripts utf8?

Comment: You need to specify character encoding in your HTML document.

Comment: i am using latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: so, what will be the suitable encoding type that should i use?

Comment: You need to be using utf8, probably utf8mb4 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: changed my collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci, does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) .

Example:

```
<?php
$item = "Zak's Laptop";
$escaped_item = mysql_escape_string($item);
printf("Escaped string: %s\n", $escaped_item);
?>
```

Comment: i need to create $item for all words that use apostrophe?

Answer (score 1):

use double qutoes for string if you were using single quotes like "your string".. it might help

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

as this is an encoding problem.

Also as  you commented that you are using PHP then this should workd as well:

```
<?php
  echo mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents('Malaysia's'),
    "HTML-ENTITIES",
    "UTF-8"
  );
?>
```

Comment: hi, i already have charset=UTF-8 in my coding. 
if i use the php script that u gave, should i create  it for all words that have apostrophe?

Comment: @zaha:- You can store it in a string and pass that string in the file_get_contents() and if you are getting it from any site/url/file then pass the url/path of the file in the file_get_contents() method.